# MariaDB/MySQL: Get checksum of InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, information-schema

How do I get a reliable checksum on an InnoDB table? I want something like the `CHECKSUM TABLE foo QUICK;` that MyISAM has, and it needs to be fast. I'm developing a tool to reliably monitor and swiftly react to changes in my database.

InnoDB tables don't update `UPDATE_TIME` in `information_schema.TABLES`, and I'm not at liberty to add an auto-updated last_update column to the table so I can do `MAX(last_update)`. Anyway, it wouldn't work for deletes. Also, I'm not happy with the race conditions that timestamps with only full-second precision introduces.

I've seen suggestions to use `NUM_ROWS` and `MODIFIED_COUNTER` from `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS` as a checksum but in my testing on MariaDB 10.0, these values are not changed on `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: you can monitor LSN from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: Actually, the MODIFIED_COUNTER not changing on UPDATES is a bug in MySQL and MariaDB. Reported as http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77301 I think I'll just wait for this to be fixed.

Comment: Quick update: MySQL decided this was a "known issue" and closed the ticket as #wontfix. MariaDB, on the other hand, accepted the bug and promptly patched it in MariaDB 10.0.23: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-8297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log sequence number increases each time a client writes to InnoDB.

```
mysql> pager grep "Log sequence number"
PAGER set to 'grep "Log sequence number"'
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
Log sequence number 243755747560
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To know which table was modified you can scan the REDO log. See the description of the REDO log file format https://www.sba-research.org/wp-content/uploads/publications/WSDF2012_InnoDB.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:  Turn on the binlog.  All changes go to it.  Monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

The MODIFIED_COUNTER not changing on UPDATEs is a bug in MySQL and MariaDB. Reported as http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77301 I think I'll just wait for this to be fixed, since it nicely solves my problem.